# Why @Value are always null when run unit-test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I write the `Spring Boot` app and I come up with a conditional scheduling service idea.
I decided to populate all properties from `application-test.yml` via `@Value` and put it in the `HashMap`.

What I don't understand why during unit-testing it always `null`, independently of if it is in a `HashMap` or `@Value` populated property.

`ReportService.java`:

```
@Component
public class ReportService {

    @Value("${reports.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${reports.enabled}")
    private Boolean enabled;

    private final Map<String, Boolean> enabledReports = new HashMap<String, Boolean>() {{
        put(name, enabled);
    }};


    boolean isEnabled(String reportName) {
        System.out.println(enabledReports.keySet() + " : " + enabledReports.values());
        System.out.println(name);

        return false;
    }
}
```

`ReportServiceTest.java`:

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.yml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ReportServiceTest {

    private ReportService reportService = new ReportService();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        reportService.isEnabled("reportName");
    }

}
```

`application-test.yml`:

```
reports:
  name: "report"
  enabled: false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to construct the map after the variables are initialized and also use @Autowired like https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121249/rkosegi mentioned:

```
@PostConstruct
public Map<String, Boolean> getEnabledReports(){
    Map<String, Boolean> stringBooleanMap = new HashMap<>();
    stringBooleanMap.put(name, enabled);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`reportService = new ReportService();` - you are creating instance of class yourself, how can Spring know that something needs to be injected?

Just let Spring to create instance for you (eg. via `@Autowired`):

```
@Autowired
private ReportService reportService;
```

Comment: I always get `null` after `@Autowired`. Do by any chance you know why it can happen?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't get it null, the only thing I can assume that your ReportServiceTest  is not scanning ReportService during the component scan, are these classes are part of same package/sub-package (just  an assumption)

Comment: @Shailesh Thx, it was exactly the problem. It was just hard to notice what is wrong. I added `@ComponentScan` for desired service and everything worked immediately.